# How to number labeled equations with different files?

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I have a file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{sec:mytitle}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and ref.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    filecolor={red}, %<----
    urlcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue}
}


\externaldocument[ex:]{external}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}

Local ref: \ref{sec:mysection}, external ref:  \ref{ex:sec:mytitle} 

\end{document}
```

I use `showonlyrefs` option in `main.tex` to minimize the numbering. However, I may have some equations that I will only call in `ref.tex`. These equations will not be numbered in `main.tex` by `showonlyrefs`. Is there any way I could overcome this?

Comment: See the mathtools manual, there is a macro similar to nocite for that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post by Overleaf: [Cross referencing with the xr package in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf) & [xr package](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-extref)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `\noeqref{sec:my_title}` in `main.tex`.

Indeed, as the comment by @daleif points out, the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) for the [mathtools package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en) discusses the `\noeqref`, which is similar to `\nocite` for bibliography items.